# Shell script to print contains of file from given line number to next given number of lines

Tags: shell, sed

By using command line arguments, I want to output the lines of a file between the required line numbers using sed. So I am unable to pass the arguments to sed command.

like i mean

`sed '$1,$2!d' file_name`

Comment: Use `""` instead of `''`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use cat -n to enumerate and then sed to print out a range of lines:

```
cat -n file_name | sed -n '1,2p'
```

Or if you want something other than a range you can print out select lines:

```
cat -n file_name | sed -n '1p;2p;4p'
```

Or to pass the range in as variables (using shell expansion):

```
cat -n file_name | sed -n "$1,$2p"
```

Comment: the comment to my question gave me the answer as well.. Thank you anyhw